# Abstract factories for injecting runtime dependencies in complex hierarchies

Tags: dependency-injection, abstract-factory

Given the following class hierarchy

- ClassA needs ClassB
- ClassB needs ClassC

we get a dependency graph like this:

```
ClassA --> ClassB --> ClassC
```

so if we use DI we inject ClassC into ClassB and ClassB into ClassA.

But now let's say ClassC is a runtime dependency (for example some kind of strategy). The proposed way to inject a runtime dependency is to introduce an abstract factory like a

```
ClassCFactory
```

Now we can inject ClassCFactory into ClassB and get the following graph

```
ClassA --> ClassB --> ClassCFactory
```

Now we have a method in ClassB which we can call to let the factory do its work. For example

```
ObjB.SelectC(MyRuntimeValue)
```

But now in our application we do not know anything about ClassB (perhaps there are some more layers involved). One solution might be to have a SelectC in ClassA

```
ObjA.SelectC(MyRuntimeValue) -(calls)-> ObjB.SelectC(MyRuntimeValue)
```

or we simply violate the Law Of Demeter and do something like

```
ObjA.ObjB.SelectC(MyRuntimeValue)
```

I think everyone agrees that the second solution is not the way to go. But the first solution also has several drawbacks, especially if we have more layers in between.

We could also pull up the factory one level to create ClassB, but is ClassB really a runtime dependency?
What solutions do you suggest? Or is it even a bad class design?

IMHO it is always better to have a dependency on what the object actually needs to do its work and not on a factory which creates the object needed. But with this thought in mind a DI container would be useless...

Answer (score 2):

> The proposed way to inject a runtime dependency is to introduce an
>   abstract factory

You don't necessarily need an abstract factory to inject things at runtime. You can use setter injection or method injection to pass a simple dependency directly to your object.

An abstract factory can be an option when you must produce objects from a range of related object *families* but don't know which family until runtime. Nothing in your example shows this is the case, so YAGNI/KISS would indicate not to use one.

> But now in our application we do not know anything about ClassB
>   (perhaps there are some more layers involved).

Could you provide details about why this is true in your scenario ? To me it seems there will always be some kind of execution context that is aware of ClassB and able to inject a C into it. It need not be the same execution context as the one that injects ClassB into an A, though.

IoC is also known as the Hollywood Principle - `"Don't call us, we'll call you"`. Who that `"we"` is and when the `"call you"` part will take place can vary a lot depending on your application, there is no hard and fast rule. If you're concerned that ObjectA might know too much about ClassC, just delegate its injection to someone else. A DI container can help a lot with that.

Comment: Ok, I will give you more concrete meanings of the classes: ClassC is an abstract class Encrytption which has different implementations for different kinds of Encryptions. ClassB is a Decorator, which decorates a FileStream with Encryption. And ClassA is is some kind of serializable object, which needs a stream to be serialized.

Comment: What determines which type of encryption is to be used ? You could have either ClassA's consumer decide and fit the 3 russian dolls together (Encryption, FileStreeamDecorator and ClassA), or some external object could pick an Encryption, put it in a FileStreamDecorator and pass it all to ClassA's consumer... Really depends on your context.

Comment: The selection of the proper encryption depends on wether we load or we save. When loading, we ask the header, which encryption is used, then we ask the user for its passphrase and start reading and decrypting. On saving we have to use the same encryption as in loading. There is a special case for exporting, where the user finally can decide which encryption to use.

Comment: Concerning the external object, which could create the streamdecorator: How do you get this working with a DI Container. Same problem. We need a stream decorator with an encryption and a stream. Both are runtime dependencies. I could do a simply create a new StreamDecorator and inject it via method injection. But then the decorator is not part of the DI container.

Comment: I mean specific instances of the Encryption - because this dependency cannot be resolved in a composition root as it depends either on the file header i have to read bevor or on a user input. The abstract factory could be used to create the correct instance of the encryption. (in the abstract example this is ClassCFactory)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "runtime dependencies"... Do you mean specific instances/named dependencies ? If it only takes a "blank" instance of Stream for the Decorator to be satisfied, then nothing gets in the way of using a DI container to provide it with the dependency. If you mean specific instances that have already been tweaked by external objects, I'm afraid you have no choice but to inject them "manually" (and I fail to see what help an Abstract Factory would have provided there)...

Comment: I can't see any benefit in passing an `MD5EncryptionFactory` to the Decorator when you could simply pass it an `MD5Encryption` (both of them are what I call "manual injection" anyway since an external, execution context-aware object has to decide which type to inject)

Comment: Agree, I just read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273583/ioc-issue-too-many-abstract-factories-for-runtime-data-dependent-classes?rq=1 and perhaps is a command the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I find runtime dependencies troublesome as well, and I think that the framework overhead of the Abstract Factories is annoying extra code that I would like not to exist. But I have yet to think of a better way of doing it unfortunately.

However in your example above I don't seem any significant difference between your two alternatives.

In one case you have

```
ObjA.ObjB.SelectC(MyRuntimeValue)
```

and in the other you would have

```
ObjA.ObjB.ObjC
```

Both of these options have the same advantages and disadvantages to my mind.

To avoid violating the Law of Demeter you have to add in a lot of pass through functions, as you note. This is not always worth the trade off, but is definitely something to consider.